# Docker Health Check and Node.js Application

Tags: node.js, docker, traefik

I've been trying to include **healthcheck** to my container, however, no matter what i do, container never seems to work. To be precise, i have the following structure:

1. Traefik Proxy
2. Node.js Application behind that proxy

All the labels for **Traefik** are included in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Whenever i try to add healthcheck, either in `Dockerfile` or in `docker-compose.yml`, application is built and listening for connections on port 443, however, when i try to access address from the browser, it always shows `404 error` (when **Traefik** is unable to proxy container).

Here is simple *service* configuration:

```
frontend:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./configuration/frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - application_environment=development
      - FRONTEND_DOMAIN=HOST_HERE
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/frontend:/app:rw
      - ./volumes/backend/.env:/.env:ro
      - ./volumes/backend/resources/lang:/backend-lang:rw
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:HOST_HERE
      - traefik.port=3000
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy
      - traefik.frontend.redirect.entryPoint=https
      - traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true
      - traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true
      - traefik.frontend.headers.browserXSSFilter=true
      - traefik.frontend.headers.contentTypeNosniff=true
      - traefik.frontend.headers.customFrameOptionsValue=SAMEORIGIN
      - traefik.frontend.headers.STSPreload=true
      - traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds=31536000
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "cd /app && yarn healthcheck"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      start_period: 60s
    networks:
      - traefik_proxy
```

And here is **healthcheck.js** file which is accessible through the command `yarn healthcheck`:

```
const http = require('https');

const options = {
    host: process.env.FRONTEND_DOMAIN,
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET',
    timeout: 2000
};

const healthCheck = http.request(options, (response) => {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`);
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        process.exit(0);
    }
    else {
        process.exit(1);
    }
});

healthCheck.on('error', function (error) {
    console.error('ERROR', error);
    process.exit(1);
});

healthCheck.end();
```

When I start the container without the **HEALTHCHECK** options (either Dockerfile or compose), it works just fine, page is displayed and when I manually execute `yarn healthcheck`, then it shows that everything is fine (I mean in the console, `STATUS: 200`). However, with automated healthcheck, Traefik will have no access to the container.

Comment: To validate your health check command, connect to the service with `bash` or `sh` and run the command. Check console output and exit code. You can print exit code with `echo $?`. Traefik expect a `0` exit code for a healthy container. If you command retuns any other code, Traefik will consider the container is down.

Comment: Do your dockerfile has a "FROM node:???" . In that case, note that actual latest node:alpine image is based on a busybox shell that contains "wget" command. You can simply use it instead of your custom script : `wget -qO- localhost:443/`. I prefer to use `localhost` instead the frontend url since i consider the healcheck as a swarm internal validation (so the public url doesn't matters here).